# Powershell GetCustomAttributes failing with could not load file or assembly

Tags: powershell, assemblies

The ps1 script should loop through the assemblies in the /bin folder, pull out the attributes, and then construct a json file with matches.  This all works for 99% of the DLLS.

But one DLL was build referencing an OLD assembly

```
Exception calling "GetCustomAttributes" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
'Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend, Version=12.2.7200.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b28c218413bdf563' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

The version in the folder is 12.2.7225.0

So this assembly is basically skipped...

This isn't an issue when the webapp runs because the web.config assembly binding just handles the version mismatch fine, but in powershell, it's tanking.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$binariesDirectory
)

$assemblies = Get-ChildItem $binariesDirectory -Filter *.dll
$controllerAssemblies = @()

foreach ($assembly in $assemblies) {
    $loadedAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($assembly.FullName)

    #THIS IS THE TEST 
    if($assembly.Name -eq "RandomSiteControlsMVC.dll"){
        Write-Output "Custom Attributes for " + $assembly.Name;
        #THIS IS WHAT FAILS
        $result = [reflection.customattributedata]::GetCustomAttributes($loadedAssembly)
        Write-Output $result;
    }

    #$loadedAssembly.CustomAttributes just returns nothing in the case of that DLL
    if ($loadedAssembly.CustomAttributes | ? { $_.AttributeType.FullName -eq "Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Infrastructure.Controllers.Attributes.ControllerContainerAttribute" -or $_.AttributeType.FullName -eq "Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Infrastructure.Controllers.Attributes.ResourcePackageAttribute"}) {
        $controllerAssemblies += $assembly.Name
    }
}

$controllerAssemblies | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content "$binariesDirectory\ControllerContainerAsembliesLocation.json" -Force
```

Is there any magical way that this could just work without that exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Try Catch statement to catch the error.
Then, in the catch statement, you could perform an action in result of the dll failing to log or... simply nothing.

For instance, in your case, since you're in a loop, you could add a `Continue` statement if the name of the assembly is the one you don't care about or throw back the error if it's a different dll. Something like this:

```
try {
    $loadedAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('blurb.dll') 
}
catch {
    # Update accordingly to your needs
    if ($assembly.Name -eq "Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.dll") {
        # Let's stop there and go to the next dll in the loop
        Continue 
    }
    else {
        # Do something if the dll that failed to load is another dll than the one you don't care
        Write-Error $_ 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep this is the answer... I handle the error, and if it's a binding one against the Telerik.Sitefinity namespace I just add it to be safe.  Thanks!